# How to use STDifference in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial

I have two tables with spatial polygons. I would like to return geometry of difference between polygons from this two tables.
I tried:

```
select  k.geom.STDifference(r.geometry) from table1 k, table2 r
```

it returns all polygons from first and second tables, not differences. How to return only diferences?

Comment: What do you mean by differences? STDifference compares 2 geometry instances and returns the set of points that are in the first but not in the second. Something tells me that you're looking to do some sort of join, but I won't know until you say what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you trying to get the difference between all objects from `table1` and `table2`? your result-set will be the amount of rows in `table1` times the rows in `table2`, e.g. `table1` has 10 rows, `table2` has 20 rows, you will have 200 rows (comparing each geometry against all the geometries from the other table).

if you want to compare specific geometries, use a `join` between `table1` and `table2`.

also i suggest you use

```
select k.geom.STDifference(r.geom).ToString() from table1 k, table2 r
```

otherwise, you might not be able to read the result.
i used this example here to try:

```
create table table1 (geom geometry);
create table table2 (geom geometry);
insert into table1 (geom) 
  values (geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 0 2, 2 2, 2 0, 0 0))', 0));
insert into table2 (geom) 
  values (geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((1 1, 3 1, 3 3, 1 3, 1 1))', 0));
select k.geom.STDifference(r.geom).ToString() from table1 k, table2 r;
```

Comment: How can I get all geometries which are in table1 and are not in table2?

Comment: I mean geometries which are not in intersection between table1 and table2.

Comment: you can `select k.geom.ToString() from table1 k full outer join table2 r on k.geom.STEquals(r.geom)=1 where r.geom is null` i guess. not sure if that is what you mean.

Comment: Thanks, You helped me a lot. That's it: select r.geometry.STSymDifference(k.geom) from table1 k full outer join table2 r on r.geometry.STIntersects(k.geom) = 1

Answer (score 0):

--- The below code provides new polygons for each polygon within table1 that intersects with a polygon in table 2. Polygons within table 1 that do not intersect with table 2 appear as null which you can later match up to the previous table (to avoid a separate row for each difference you'll need to merge the join polygon geography/geometry into a single row ---

```
SELECT
A.a_geom.STDifference(B.b_geom) AS c_geom
,A.a_geom.STDifference(B.b_geom).STArea() AS c_geom_area
,A.RowID
INTO [table3]
FROM [table1] AS A
FULL JOIN [table2] AS B
ON A.a_geom.STIntersects(B.b_geom)=1
```

--- Now you'll need to include polygons in table 1 that do not intersect with polygons in table 2 which you can do by simply copying/matching the null rows in table 3 with table 1 ---

```
UPDATE [table3]
SET c_geom = B.a_geom
FROM [table 3] AS A
JOIN [table1] AS B
ON A.RowID = B.RowID
WHERE A.c_geom IS NULL
```